# Android URL parsing

Tags: java, android, metadata, url-parsing

I am working on an android video downloader. The app loads the links in WebView and then gets the videos URL so, that app can download the required video. Currently, it loads only a single link of the video I want to parse the URL with every available video quality like 360p, 720p, and if possible also the "audio-only" option to download the audio-only. I want my app to parse links [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V486s.png) not for any particular site video URL but for different URLs. Here is a sample [URL](https://video.flhe7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.25447-2/100376086_2275976509378652_3311878361181404491_n.mp4?_nc_cat=109&_nc_sid=5aebc0&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRfNDI2X2NyZl8yM19tYWluXzMuMF9mcmFnXzJfdmlkZW8ifQ%3D%3D&_nc_ohc=eFzKgYCIuNoAX_t1vAu&_nc_ht=video.flhe7-1.fna&oh=3ab1a227927daea69745353d98eeb04f&oe=5F3BD719&bytestart=989&byteend=2616).

Comment: What you showed us in "links like that" is a dialog box, created by some existing software, and not a link nor a URL.

Comment: Yes, I also want to prase the URL as shown in the attached image. As mention, I want to parse different sites video URLs (facebook, dailymotion, vk ...) like that not the URL of particular site videos.

Comment: A URL is a sequence of characters, typically starting with "http", and not a screenshot.

Comment: I also mention that I want to parse the URL like that's why I attached the screenshot. Well, I edit the question please check it.

Comment: No way. You're lost. That URL doesn't contain any hints on multiple resolutions, so I don't think anyone can parse multiple resolutions out of that URL.

Comment: I am also struggling with it ... any parsing libraries you can suggest me?

Comment: Everything said.